# How to create a SQLite3 table with column names from a list?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm storing patients' daily blood pressure data in an SQLite3 table. Each patient corresponds to a row, each date corresponds to a column. How do I initialize this table with the column names being the dates from a Python Pandas series? Perhaps something like:

```
DATE_LIST = pandas.date_range(start_date, end_date)
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE bloodpressure DATE_LIST REAL''')
```

The above will create a table with a single column named DATE_LIST, which is not what I want. I want to use the dates in DATE_LIST as column names.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the 1NF of databases. Consider restructuring the database to follow the normal form.

In simpler terms, each row should be a patients blood pressure at some date.

```
patient_id | bloodpressure | date
-----------+---------------+-----------
101        | 120/80        | 2016-08-04
101        | 130/84        | 2016-08-03  
102        | 150/90        | 2016-08-03
```

The SQL statement to create this could look something like

```
CREATE TABLE bloodpressure (
    patient_id integer,
    bloodpressure text,
    date text,
    primary key(patient_id)
)
```

Comment: Could you explain why I'm breaking the 1NF? According to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/first-normal-form.htm) I should have no repeating groups of data. The solution proposed in this post repeats date as many times as there are patients. It becomes unwieldy when the number of blood pressure readings for each patient is very large.